# How to get Image data from SQL Server, Write To File, Save File to Disk using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get attachments (images, word documents, etc.) stored as an Image datatype from a SQL Server database. The attachments can be of any file type, but I'm just trying to get a .jpg to download successfully.

I'm able to save the file to my local drive, but it appears to be corrupting the file in the process.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Retrieve binary data of type IMAGE from SQL Server Database.
2. Create a file from the binary data.
3. Save the file to a local directory.

My CODE:

```
    public void ProcessRequest()
    {
        //Get the ticket number from query string
        _ticketNumber = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_DBConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string fileName = ""; //Holds the file name retrieved from DB
        byte[] data; // Holds the IMAGE data from DB

        using (conn)
        {
            using (cmd)
            {

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT File_Name, Data FROM Tickets_All INNER JOIN Attachments ON Tickets_All.ID = Attachments.[Object_ID] WHERE Ticket = @Ticket";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ticket", _ticketNumber);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        fileName = reader.GetString(0);
                        data = (byte[])reader["Data"];

                        if (data != null)
                        {
                            SaveData(fileName, data);
                        }
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();

            }
        }

    protected bool SaveData(string FileName, byte[] Data)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Windows\temp\test.jpg";

        try
        {
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(path));
            writer.Write(Data);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Please forgive me if the code isn't up to par with best practices, I'm more of a VB programmer and I've never had to do this before. I'm just trying to get a working example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Microsoft example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: My question is do you know that the file type you are trying to download as a .jpg IS a .jpg?

Comment: Yes, I know the file name and file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input everyone. After doing some additional testing, I think that the data being retrieved from the database has been compressed in some way. I'm able to insert and pull out files programmatically just fine, the problem comes in when the application puts the data into the database (3rd party software). I'm going to look into the compression what I can come up with.

Comment: Not an answer. The question is not about "is data compressed" but "How do I load it and write it to disc".

Comment: I can see your point here, @TomTom. I think this answer essentially says, "The question was based on an incorrect premise". Arguably, that should be a comment. It probably also means the question should be closed.

Comment: I agree, it should be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the Image.FromStream method to do this : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream(v=vs.110).aspx

```
protected bool SaveData(string FileName, byte[] Data)
{
    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Data)))
    {
        image.Save("MyImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    return true;
}
```